# Why do I have problem when I train my model in pytorch?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I'm new with PyTorch and AI but I have some trouble when I try to train my model.

I just create my `Dataset` and my `Dataloader`

```
    train_dataset = TensorDataset(tensor_train,tensor_label)
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset,batch_size=32,shuffle=True)
```

And after this my criterion and optimiser

```
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    optimiser=optim.Adam(net.parameters(),lr=0.2)
```

And I try to train it with

```
    for epoch in range(10):
           for data in train_dataloader:
                inputs,labels = data
                output = net(torch.Tensor(inputs))
                loss = criterion(output,labels.to(device))
                optimiser.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimiser.step()
```

But I got this error

```
    d:\py\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in <lambda>(t)
321             Module: self
322         """
    --> 323         return self._apply(lambda t: t.type(dst_type))
324 
325     def float(self):

TypeError: dtype must be a type, str, or dtype object
```

I will be happy if someone finds the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems:

1) Your dataloader outputs a tensor, so you don't need to create another tensor. Just do this:

```
output = net(inputs)
```

2) Are you sending your model to `device`? If yes, you need to send the `inputs` as well. If not, you don't need to do this with the outputs:

```
loss = criterion(output,labels)
```

However, I'm not sure if the error you're getting is not related to these 2 points. Consider posting the line in your code (instead of the lib). Also, consider including more information about `tensor_train` and `tensor_label`

Answer (score 0):

Ty for reply but the problem was coming from another thing
I was creating my model like this

```
class Perceptron(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self):
         super(Perceptron,self).__init__()
         self.type = nn.Linear(4,3)
     def forward(self,x):
          return self.type(x)
net = Perceptron().to(device)
```

and the nn.Module was already getting a type attribute thats why i was getting this error( i thing) , then i solve by change self.type by self.anythingElseThanType